# How many observations are preferred for a difference-in-difference analysis?

Tags: econometrics, small-sample, difference-in-difference

I'm doing a difference-in-difference analysis using export data split by four SITC codes. I have 442 observations in total and my dependent variable is total exports for the four codes which has 58 observations (treatment and control included). However I am concerned that this is not a large enough sample size and I don't have enough to undertake a differenece-in-difference. Is it still possible to conduct such an analysis and if not, how many observations would be appropriate?

Comment: By _observation_ I understand what is variously called a row, case or record and no doubt other names too. What difference do you report between 442 and 58? Is it that you have missing values in 384 observations or are you counting something else?

Comment: Someone with your name is posting on similar topics on Statalist. If it's you, that's fine, but note that in Stata observation does mean strictly what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes that is me on statalist. Essentially, I have export data from 1990-2018 for two countries. This data is recorded by four different SITC trade codes(SITC 2,3,5,6)  which were added together to get a measure of total exports of these four codes. This is my dependent variable but as a result, the number of observations on the dependent variable is low since the separate codes have been added together. Would this necessarily be a problem in conducting diff-in-diff?

Comment: Smaller sample size than you would want is always less than ideal, but what would be a bigger sample size here, and would it really help?  I am not an economist, but the most obvious possibility here is to seek export data for earlier than 1990. But the longer back you go, the more hidden variables are at work producing extra variability. I don't think there can be any precise rules or even rules of thumb or what sample size is enough. I might be thought facetious if I said that a sample size is large enough if you can convince a competent reviewer that your analysis shows a clear result.

Comment: I don't think many people focused on econometrics hang out here. Other than Statalist, I don't follow other forums enough to suggest where else to ask.

Comment: Was your question not addressed [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1548518-did-coefficient-is-insignificant-for-country-fe-but-adding-country-and-time-fe-changes-coefficient-sign-and-becomes-significant)? In a *generalized* difference-in-differences framework, your total number of predictors is getting awfully close to the total number of observations.